# 'line' followed by two or more numbers

Tags: grammaticality

I'm writing an errata list of a math paper. Which one of the following three statements is appropriate?

1. Page 10, line 34 and 45: ...
2. Page 10, line 34 and line 45: ...
3. Page 10, lines 34 and 45: ...

Comment: #2 and #3 are acceptable, #3 is more common in my experience.